# Python Gekko: Increasing value of objective_convergence_tolerance for Solver=2 (BPOPT)

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

Is there a way to increase the value of objective_convergence_tolerance  for Solver=2 (BPOPT)?

It seems to be working only for Solver = 1 and 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 parts that are checked for convergence including:

1. max(abs(g + a^T * lam - zL + zU))/s_d
2. max(abs(c))
3. max(abs(diag[x-xL s-sL]*zL - mu))/s_c
4. max(abs(diag[xU-x sU-s]*zU - mu))/s_c

The maximum of these 4 parts must be less than the convergence tolerance. Right now there is no separate objective function convergence criterion. Gekko has 3 solvers that are included with the publicly available version including:

1. APOPT
2. BPOPT
3. IPOPT

The BPOPT solver isn't typically one one of the best solvers if you'd like to try `m.options.SOLVER=1` (APOPT) or `m.options.SOLVER=3` (IPOPT).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The BPOPT solver is actually the best for my system. I tested the others, and they don't converge/find solution.